# Target checkout page but not order-received page in Woocommerce

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, woocommerce, conditional-statements

I'm linking some .js in my `functions.php` this way:

```
if(get_query_var('pagename')==='checkout') {
    wp_enqueue_script('script', 'my.js', array('jquery'), 1.1, true);
}
```

`my.js` is where i check for some checkout form input fields.
Now i see that `my.js` is linked also in the order-received page (that is a 'sub-page' of the checkout page, i know!), and this causes some errors because the checkout form isn't there anymore.

How to conditionally execute some code in the checkout page but not in order-received one?

Thanx.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To target checkout page **avoiding "order-received" or "order-pay" endpoints** use:

```
if( is_checkout() && ! ( is_wc_endpoint_url( 'order-pay' ) || is_wc_endpoint_url( 'order-received' ) ) ) {
    wp_enqueue_script('script', 'my.js', array('jquery'), 1.1, true);
}
```

Tested and work.

Answer (score 0):

Try using is_checkout_pay_page() function:

```
if(is_checkout_pay_page()) {
    wp_enqueue_script('script', 'my.js', array('jquery'), 1.1, true);
}
```

Comment: it doesn't work. But thanx, your answer inspired me to look in the right direction...